# Remove folder name with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new with php and htaccess and I found a lot of topics about it, but no one solve my problem... I am using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!pages/).*)$ /pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

to remove pages from my url, for example:

http://myurl.com/pages/index.php

changes to

http://myurl.com/index.php

This code is working good, but the problem is when I write manually url with /pages I can't remove it! How can I redirect or do something to remove /pages from url if I write it manually?

EDIT:

I found a solution if someone has the same problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!pages/).*)$ /pages/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /pages/
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!pages/).*)$ pages/$1 [L,NC,E=REWRITTEN:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REWRITTEN} !=1
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_REWRITTEN} !=1
RewriteRule ^pages(/.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Let me know any problems. I removed the opening slash on your substitution as you were doubling it up there since it's not included in htaccess matches.

Comment: That coused excessive redirect, but I found the solution: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!pages/).*)$ /pages/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /pages/
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Thanks anyway for help!

Comment: Thanks Matheus. I've been working out what was wrong with my answer. Finally found it and fixed. Glad you found a solution. You should still remove the first forward slash from your first RewriteRule's substitution. It will work but you're doubling up the forward slash which is not good. Just change it to `RewriteRule ^((?!pages/).*)$ pages/$1 [L,NC]`.

Comment: You could accept my answer now if you like. It works now and would be appreciated. You can even upvote it now you have enough reputation! :)